# Uploadify is destroying session before upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, uploadify

We all know that Uploadify has a session problem. As I browse through the posts, I found the solution for the problem which is I need to pass session through ajax.

But the problem is, whenever I go to a page which contain uploadify things, It destroys the Session usually after refresh. I **didn't even upload anything.** '.

For example, I got to a page which contain uploadify scripts. And **without doing anything**, I went to other page and it automatically *redirect to login page** which means **session is destroyed**.

Does the Uploadify does the ajax call before I upload the files or even before pressing the upload button?

Is there any ways to solve this?

This is my Ajax code:

```
$(function() {
$('#file_upload1').uploadify({
       'formData'     : {
         'PHPSESSID': '<?=session_id()?>',
         'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
         'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
        },
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify1.php?id=<? echo $id; ?>&state=<? echo strtolower($state); ?>'

         });
});
```

This is my top PHP code :

```
session_id($_POST['PHPSESSID']);

include "func.php";
sec_session_start();
```

`sec_session_start();` is a function. So , `sec_session_start();` codes :

```
function sec_session_start() {
        $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
        $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
        $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
        session_set_cookie_params(86400);
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
        session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
        session_start(); // Start the php session
        session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
}
```

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what goes wrong and show the code you are using to address the problem?

Comment: How do you know it's the session acting up? Are you sure there are no other JavaScript errors that cause the page to reload?

Comment: Yea. I tried removing the path to jqeur.uploadify.js and SESSION does not destroyed.

Comment: And also, I've printed the session and it returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried replacing the `PHPSESSID` with `sec_session_id` ?

```
$(function() {
$('#file_upload1').uploadify({
       'formData'     : {
         '<?=session_name()?>': '<?=session_id()?>',
         'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
         'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
        },
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify1.php?id=<? echo $id; ?>&state=<? echo strtolower($state); ?>'

         });
});
```

On top of your PHP: `session_id($_POST['sec_session_id']);`

Also, `session_name($session_name)` should be executed before `session_set_cookie_params`.

```
function sec_session_start() {
        $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
        session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
        $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
        $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
        session_set_cookie_params(86400);
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
        session_start(); // Start the php session
        session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
}
```